# Windows service not showing up in installed services (and hence unable to start)

Tags: c#, windows-services

I just built a very simple Windows service to test something and built it to get the .exe. As per [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a50syb3.aspx) in MSDN, I also installed the service using the Visual Studio Command Prompt 2010 (ran as administrator) `installutil TestService.exe`.

When using the `installutil` command, everything runs fine and I get a message saying that the service has been installed. Further, to start the service when I check inside the Services node (in Server Explorer in Visual Studio), I do not see any service named `TestService.exe`.

Also, Start Menu -> My Computer (Right Click) -> Manage -> Services and Application -> Services does not show the `TestService.exe` through which I could start the service.

Any suggestions how do I start the service?

Code inside `OnStart` function:

```
Process[] testProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad.exe");
if (testProcess.Length == 0)
    File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\User1\Desktop\service.txt", "nothing");

else
    File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\User1\Desktop\service.txt", "run");
```

Comment: Have you refreshed the services list? If it is still not there, the installation probably _failed_. See the `install.log` file to see for certain.

Comment: @Oded: Yes, I refreshed nd resrtaed Visual Studio but the service does not appear. Install.log shows the service insatlled successfully http://pastebin.com/8QJhi97H

Comment: It won't show `TestService.exe`, unless that's the display name you've set on the Service component in your project - this defaults to Service1. Is Service1 in the list?

Comment: Restarting Visual Studio won't help. It's the service control manager that needs to be refreshed.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: No, Service1 is also not in the list (The File name inside the project for the Service is Service1)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have had problems with `installutil` before and found using the `sc` command works whereas `installutil` didn't.

Try installing your service with this command:

```
sc create servicename binPath= serviceexe.exe
```

Comment: The problem with `sc create` is that it doesn't understand .NET installer classes, so it will not run them. This can cause problems with e.g. the event source not being created.

Comment: @Bali C: This kind of worked and the service appears in the Services inside Server explorer. But now, I am not able to start this (since there's no start option here ) screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/oRaXs.png

Comment: @user1240679 Can you start the service in Services console? `services.msc`

Comment: @user1240679 Or try `net start servicename`

Comment: @BaliC: No, there appear some error when I tried from services.msc. Screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/gTOcz.png

Comment: @user1240679 I did a quick google on the error, it looks as though its the service exe file thats wrong, which is why the installation isn't working. Is that all the code you have in the `OnStart` method? The last time I wrote a service I seem to remember having to start a thread from there so it could return to confirm the method had started, maybe try that?

Comment: @BaliC: Yes, this is the only code that I have in the OnStart method

Answer (score 9):

I just had this issue and was able to resolve it with the following steps. If you skip these steps, your setup project will build and copy your files to the correct directory; however, they will not register your binary as a service without these steps.

1. In Solution Explorer, right-click the setup project, point to View, then choose Custom Actions. The Custom Actions editor appears.
2. In the Custom Actions editor, right-click the Custom Actions node and choose Add Custom Action. The Select Item in Project dialog box appears.
3. Double-click the application folder in the list box to open it, select primary output from MyNewService (Active), and click OK. The primary output is added to all four nodes of the custom actions: Install, Commit, Rollback, and Uninstall.
4. Build the setup project.

Comment: This one worked for me.  Couldn't figure out why the service was missing from the services.msc and  had forgotten (doh!)to add the service to the installer.

Comment: In vs2012 have no "Setup project" option how to solve it there ??

Answer (score 1):

While working in VS 2013, I ran into this issue when I added the installer by right clicking on the project and adding a new item of type `Installer Class`.  The key difference is that you need to right click on the `Design View` of the `Windows Service` and click `Add Installer`.

For full details on .Net 4.5 and 4.6 see [Creating a service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k985bc9(v=vs.110).aspx), [Adding Installers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ddhy0byf(v=vs.110).aspx), and [Installing a Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd8zc8ha(v=vs.110).aspx)